# How to use RegularGridInterpolator with datasets with different dimensions (lat/lon/time)?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, interpolation, netcdf

I want to interpolate two NetCDF data sets, one being observation and one being predicted. I want to interpolate a single predicted variable (i.e. 'hs' in modFile in my example) onto the lat, lon, and time of the observation data (obsFile). The structure of the satellite observation dataset (obsFile) is that everything is dimensioned by time only (no lat or lon dimensions, they are variables). The lat and lon value of observations are also much finer resolution than the predicted values since these are along track values, written from the satellite every few seconds. The readout from opening observation netcdf with xarray:

```
xarray.Dataset
Dimensions:
time: 53595
Coordinates:
time
(time)
datetime64[ns]
2021-04-01T00:00:00.689500800 .....
lat
(time)
float64
...
lon
(time)
float64
...
Data variables:
...
swh
(time)
float32
...
```

The predicted dataset (modFile) is dimensioned with time AND lat and lon values. So, each variable is 3D while the satellite file variables are 1D (only time):

```
xarray.Dataset
Dimensions:
latitude: 721, longitude: 1440, time: 25
Coordinates:
longitude
(longitude)
float32
0.0 0.25 0.5 ... 359.2 359.5 359.8
latitude
(latitude)
float32
-90.0 -89.75 -89.5 ... 89.75 90.0
time
(time)
datetime64[ns]
2021-04-01 ... 2021-04-02
Data variables:
...
hs
(time, latitude, longitude)
float32
...
```

Here's my attempted code for 3D interpolation in 3D space (time, lat, lon):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator as rgi

latsat = np.array(obsFile['lat'])
lonsat = np.array(obsFile['lon'])
timesat = np.array(obsFile['time'])
latww = np.array(modFile['latitude'])
lonww = np.array(modFile['longitude'])
timeww = np.array(modFile['time'])
hsww = np.array(modFile['hs'])

my_interpolating_function = rgi((timeww, latww, lonww), hsww)
Vi = my_interpolating_function(np.array([timesat, latsat, lonsat]))
```

And my value error saying it's out of bounds as this interpolation creates a (53595 x 53595 x 53595) satellite array vs the modeled (25 x 721 x 1440) array:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-db49322d1a44> in <module>
      2 from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator as rgi
      3 my_interpolating_function = rgi((timeww, latww, lonww), hsww)
----> 4 Vi = my_interpolating_function(array([timesat, latsat, lonsat]))
      5 
      6 # fn = RegularGridInterpolator((latsat, lonsat, timesat), hsww)

~/anaconda3/envs/aoes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py in __call__(self, xi, method)
   2471             raise ValueError("The requested sample points xi have dimension "
   2472                              "%d, but this RegularGridInterpolator has "
-> 2473                              "dimension %d" % (xi.shape[1], ndim))
   2474 
   2475         xi_shape = xi.shape

ValueError: The requested sample points xi have dimension 53595, but this RegularGridInterpolator has dimension 3
```

Any ideas how to restructure my satellite data to interpolate properly or a different function?

Comment: Without some data sample it is hard to do something... In any case, I would avoid doing interpolation directly in 3D space and instead spatially interpolate each time-moment data and afterwards, if required, make the interpolation in time domain. In any case, you cannot just remove `num2date` function as interpolation expects time information as floating numbers and not dates.

Comment: I've added better info to explain the issues with interpolating more. I currently do not know how to spatially interpolate each time-moment data and afterwards. Would that require looping? I'll eventually be scaling this up to 2+ million data points so looping would be too time intensive.